# Can I connect to my printer when IT seems to prohibit connection from the Wi-Fi to the wired LAN network?

Tags: windows, networking, mac, printing, printer

I am working at a university. I have an office with a Mac and a printer (EPSON WF-7840). The Mac is connected to the university intranet via a wired LAN connection and can access the printer. My laptop (windows 10) is only connected to the student wifi via my own cerfiticate.

The problem is that I cannot access the printer from the laptop. It seems that it is only accessible via the wired LAN connections. I have asked the university IT, but they did not respond. I also tried to connect to the printer via Wi-Fi Direct, but that also does not work because windows claims that the "driver is not available". I also downloaded the EPSON software tools specifically for this printer but it seems that there is no option for a Wi-Fi directy setup.

There are a few other ideas I had:

- I can always move the files to my Mac and print them from there. But this can be tedious in the long run.
- It is possible to share the printer from the Mac. But it seems that my laptop then cannot find the shared printer.
- Is it maybe possible to share the printer directly via Wi-Fi from the mac, to have a Wi-Fi directy printer on the Mac?

Comment: If the printer has a USB port, you might be able to directly connect it to the laptop.

Comment: Pretty sure it is because the wifi infrastructure is totally separate from the wired LAN as should be for security purposes, use the USB port if possible

Comment: Most likely, yes. Even though I can access the Mac via SSH, which is necessary for my work.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Answer (score 1):

The Student Wifi is probably separated from the normal University LAN for security reasons. There is no way you are going to be able make a network connection between the laptop and the Mac. (And for the same reason the printer probably has Wifi Direct (if it supports that, not all do) disabled.)

That printer has a USB port at the back. Simply plug a USB cable between your laptop and the printer.

Comment: This is going to be the easiest and quickest way to get your printer working.  If the printer is far from your PC, you can get 10ft/20ft USB cable extenders off of your favorite e-commerce site, as well as runners to keep them against the wall.

Comment: That works and I have tried it before. But I (with the printer) have moved to a different office since then and it is now 3m away from me. I would definitely need a very long cable (I think about 7m/22ft) because of the "topography" of the office.